# Proving a recursive formula given a sumation of powers

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion

I was trying to prove that given $$
a_n=\sum_{k=1}^m b_k c_k^n
$$ then  $a_n$ could be expressed by the recursive formula $$
a_n=-\sum_{k=1}^m u_ka_{n-k}
$$ where $\prod_{j=1}^m(X-c_j)=X^m+\sum_{j=1}^n u_jX^{m-j}$

I believe that it follows from the Newton identities but I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
Then Newton's identities can be stated as

$$ke_{k}(x_{1},\ldots ,x_{n})=\sum _{i=1}^{k}(-1)^{i-1}e_{k-i}(x_{1},\ldots ,x_{n})p_{i}(x_{1},\ldots ,x_{n}),$$
valid for all n ≥ 1 and n ≥k ≥ 1.